# How to Encrypt and Decrypt an image in WP8?

Tags: c#, encryption, windows-phone-8

I want to Encrypt  an image and save in Isolated storage and image decryption while reading.I am able to do normal text data but I didn't find solution for an image.And further I need to encrypt and decrypt PDF/Doc files.
Below is my code

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
compressedStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

using (IsolatedStorageFile isStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
     if (!isStore.FileExists(selectedImageName)) 
     using (IsolatedStorageFileStream targetStream = isStore.OpenFile(selectedImageName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
     {
          byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];
          int bytesRead = -1;

          while ((bytesRead = compressedStream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) > 0)
          {
              targetStream.Write(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
          }
     }
}
```

To encrypt normal text using below code

```
public static byte[] Encrypt(string text, string strCacheKey)
{
    try
    {
         return ProtectedData.Protect((Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text)), GetToken(strCacheKey));
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {             
    }
    return new byte[0];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add some code? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got answer to encrypt/decrypt Images

Encryption Code:

```
 public static byte[] EncryptImage(byte[] encryptedimage, string strCacheKey)
    {
        try
        {
            return ProtectedData.Protect(encryptedimage, GetToken(strCacheKey));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
        return new byte[0];
    }
```

Decryption Code:

```
public static byte[] DecryptImage(byte[] decryptedimage, string strCacheKey)
    {
        try
        {
            return ProtectedData.Unprotect(decryptedimage, GetToken(strCacheKey));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
        return new byte[0];
    }
```

Code for storing in Isolated Storage:

```
 byte[] ibytes = new byte[attachmentStream.Length]; 
 byte[] ImageByte = TextImageEncryptionDecryption.EncryptImage(ibytes, App.cacheKey);

  using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
  using (IsolatedStorageFileStream targetStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(selectedImageName,
                                   FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, store))
                    {
                        targetStream.Write(ImageByte, 0, ImageByte.Length);
                    }
```

Code to Read image from ISO:

```
   using (var stream = iso.OpenFile(name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                        {
                         byte[] ImgStr =  ReadFully(stream);
                         byte[] Img = TextImageEncryptionDecryption.DecryptImage(ImgStr, App.cacheKey);
                         Stream Imagestream = new MemoryStream(Img);
                         image.SetSource(Imagestream);
                         imgAttach = image;
                        }
                        return imgAttach;
                    }
```

Cheers !!